# destructuring object into multiple object assignment

Tags: javascript, object, object-destructuring

I have an object like so:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5
}
```

I want to create multiple object literals out of it. So:

```js
const obj1 = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2
}

const obj2 = {
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this using an object destructing assignment?

Something like:

```js
const { {a, b}: obj1, {c, d, e}: obj2} = obj;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to achieve this using object destructuring assignment?

No, it is not possible. However, you can write a function to split an object by its property names into multiple objects like this:

```js
function splitObject (obj, ...propertyGroups) {
  return propertyGroups.map(group => {
    const o = {};
    for (const key of group) o[key] = obj[key];
    return o;
  });
}

const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5,
};

const [obj1, obj2] = splitObject(obj, ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']);

console.log({obj, obj1, obj2});
```

By returning the sub-objects in a tuple, you have the freedom to destructure it, naming each one according to your preference.